# Openfire Memory Leak - How to make it Stable and Robust?

Tags: java, jvm, centos, openfire

I find it very difficult to make a stable implementation of the openfire server in my website,

no matter how much memory i allocate to the openfire JVM, it crashes after 24 hours every day. (currently 8 GB i have as JVM memory) with settings as below with OPEN JDK 64 bit server

```
OPENFIRE_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx8192m -Xss256k -Xoss256k -XX:ThreadStackSize=256 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xloggc:/opt/openfire/logs/gc.log"
```

Is there any particular settings that i need to set make it more robust and stable ?

see attached below

[image]

Comment: Do you know that it is running out of memory, and that is the source of your problem?

If it leaks, you may need to find a different release of it which doesn't, or use something else.

Comment: yes its memory problem, people says openfire can hadnle upto 1500 users since java is platform independant i dont knw why only systems has this problems must be a configuration or optimaization problems

Comment: What version are you using and what functionality is being exercised?  There was a known leak regarding PEP and pubsub, but that was fixed a couple of versions ago.